# How to use values of arrays of objects as condition check statements (like if/else) when the array has some null values in it. NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have an array of objects called "Examroom" with a string (name) parameter and int (waitTime) parameter.

The client is supposed to enter a name, and then the program can add it to an object in a new array element (CheckIn method).

the client can also enter a name, and the program iterates through the array, comparing the uppercase of the user input to the uppercase of the names stored in the array element objects (CheckOut method).

In CheckIn, I am able to retrieve the contents of the elements just fine, however in CheckOut I'm unable to use a call to the array using a loop (ExamRoom[i].name == n.toUpperCase) and get a NullPointerException.

The array has a size of 4 (4 ExamRooms) and sometimes elements need to be empty if there aren't any people to fill them. I need to use an array and cannot use something flexible like an arrayList. Help please.

Originally, CheckIn did not work because I was using a for statement with i and "ExamRoom[i].name"/ ExamRoom[i].waitTime. I eventually replaced i with a counter (countNames), and the for loop with simply incrementing countNames after every time the method ran. This worked, but i am not sure why, or how I can do something similar to CheckOut- think it needs the for loops it has.

ExamRoom is an array of Patient objects
Patient:

```
public class Patient 
{
    
    public String name;
    public int waitTime;
    Patient (String name, int waitTime)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
    }
}
```

calls to methods from (Main) Menu Class:

```
                final int NumRm = 4;
            int WaitTime = -1;
            Patient[] ExamRoom = new Patient[NumRm];
            Queue<Patient> WaitingRoom = new LinkedList<Patient>();
            switch (choice) 
            {
                case -1:
                    break;
                    
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Check in:");
                    System.out.println("---------");
                        System.out.println("Enter the name of the patient you would like to check in.");  
                            String InPatientName = kbReader.nextLine();
         
                    Doctors_Office.CheckIn(InPatientName, WaitTime, ExamRoom, WaitingRoom);
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Check out:");
                    System.out.println("----------");
                        System.out.println("Enter the name of the person you would like to check out.");
                    String OutPatientName = kbReader.nextLine();
                    
                    Doctors_Office.CheckOut(OutPatientName, WaitTime, ExamRoom, WaitingRoom);
                    break;

The methods CheckIn and CheckOut, located in Doctors_Office Class - i dont think the contructor is doing anything becuase the methods themselves have what they need



public class Doctors_Office 
{
    static int i,j,k,l;
    static int EmptyExmRoom;
    static Boolean ExamRmFull; 
    static Boolean ExamRmEmpty;
    static Boolean WaitingRmEmpty;
    static int countNames = 0;
    static int comb = 5;
    int waitTime;
    String name;
    
    public Doctors_Office(String name, int waitTime, Patient[] ExamRoom, Queue<Patient> WaitingRoom)
    {
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    
    
    public static void CheckIn (String n, int wt, Patient[] ExamRoom, Queue<Patient> WaitingRoom)
    {
        
        if (countNames < ExamRoom.length)
        {
            int RmNmbr = countNames + 1;
            wt = 0;
            ExamRoom[countNames] = new Patient(n.toUpperCase(), wt);//Enter Patient into the empty exam room.
            countNames += 1;
            System.out.println("The Patient was checked into Exam Room number " + RmNmbr + ".");
            System.out.println(ExamRoom[countNames - 1].name + "    bloop   " + ExamRoom[countNames - 1].waitTime);

        }
        else if (countNames >= ExamRoom.length)//Exam Rooms are full
        {
            wt = comb;
            WaitingRoom.add(new Patient(n.toUpperCase(),wt));//Enter Patient into the waiting room.
            System.out.println("The Exam Rooms are currently full. Patient was sent to the Waiting Room.");
            System.out.println(WaitingRoom.peek().name + " has a wait time of " + WaitingRoom.peek().waitTime + " minutes.");
            countNames += 1;
            comb += 5;
        }
    }
    
    public static void CheckOut (String n, int wt, Patient[] ExamRoom, Queue<Patient> WaitingRoom)
    {
        int PatientExmRm;
        int index;
        int position;
        //if (Doctors_Office.ExamRmEmpty == true)
        if (countNames == 0)    
        {
            System.out.println("There are not any Patients in the Exam Room to check out.");
        }
        //else if (Doctors_Office.ExamRmEmpty == false)// the Exam Room has patients.
        else if (countNames != 0)   // the Exam Room has patients.
        {
//          String pName = ExamRoom[countNames - 1].name;
//          System.out.println(pName);
            try {
            for(i = 0; i < ExamRoom.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("bloop1");
                if (ExamRoom[i].name == n.toUpperCase())// check if the target patient is in the exam room.
                //if (ExamRoom[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n) )
                {
                    System.out.println("bloop2");
                    PatientExmRm = i +1;// Exam Room number that the patient is checking out of.
                    index = i;
                    Patient[] Copy = new Patient[ExamRoom.length - 1];
                    for (j = 0, k = 0; j < ExamRoom.length; j++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("bloop3");
                        if (j == index)
                        {
                            System.out.println("bloop4");
                            continue;
                        }
                        Copy[k++] = ExamRoom[j];
                        ExamRoom = Copy;
                        countNames -= 1;
                    }
                    System.out.println("The Patient " + n + " was sucessfully checked out of Exam Room " + PatientExmRm + ".");
                    
                    if (WaitingRoom.isEmpty() == true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("There are not any Patients in the Waiting Room at this time");
                    }
                    else if (WaitingRoom.isEmpty() == false)
                    {
                        position = index;
                        String QueuedPatient = WaitingRoom.peek().name;
                        Patient[] New = new Patient[ExamRoom.length + 1];
                        for (l = 0; l < ExamRoom.length + 1; l++)
                        {
                            if (l < position - 1)
                            {
                                New[l] = ExamRoom[l];
                            }
                            else if (l == position - 1)
                            {
                                New[l] = WaitingRoom.peek();
                                New[l] = WaitingRoom.remove();
                                                        New[l] = Patient(WaitingRoom.peek().name, WaitingRoom.peek().waitTime);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                New[l] = ExamRoom[l - 1];
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("The Patient " + QueuedPatient + " was moved from the Waiting Room to Exam Room number " + PatientExmRm + ".");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("The patient you are looking for is not in an Exam Room.");
                }
                
            }
            }catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }


any attempts to retrieve values from the array elements in a for loop yield an exception
I added in a try/catch, which stopped the program from quitting, but did not resolve the issue.


Thank you.
```

Comment: Taking a quick look at your code, this line looks suspicious: `ExamRoom[i].name == n.toUpperCase())`  Take a look at this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: `Patient[] ExamRoom = new Patient[NumRm];` seems to be getting re-initialised on each loop of your menu - so when you add a user, a new `ExamRoom` is create before you want to remove them. `ExamRoom[i].name == n.toUpperCase()` isn't how you should be comparing `String`s, use `String#equals` or `String#equalsIgnoreCase` instead (ie `n.equalsIgnoreCase(ExamRoom[i].name)`)

Comment: Off-topic: You might want to review Java naming conventions [at Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) or [other sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+naming+conventions).  Further off-topic / style: You don't have to compare `boolean` variables to a `true` or `false` constant.  If `foo` is a `boolean`, `if (foo == true)` is equivalent to `if (foo)`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have compounding issues

## First...

`ExamRoom` (and `WaitingRoom`) are been initialised on each loop of your menu...

```
final int NumRm = 4;
int WaitTime = -1;
Patient[] ExamRoom = new Patient[NumRm];
Queue<Patient> WaitingRoom = new LinkedList<Patient>();
switch (choice) 
{
```

so any previously stored information is lost.

## Second...

`ExamRoom[i].name == n.toUpperCase()` isn't how you should be comparing `String`s. Use `String#equals` or `String#equalsIgnoreCase` instead (ie `n.equalsIgnoreCase(ExamRoom[i].name)`)

## Third...

There seems to be a disconnect between how your `Doctors_Office` is intended to be used and how you're using it.

What I mean is, the constructor asks for the `waitTime` and `examRoom` properties, but you ignore these and seem to be passing them via (`static`) methods instead.

```
public Doctors_Office(String name, int waitTime, Patient[] examRoom) {
    this.waitTime = waitTime;
    this.name = name;
}
```

I would recommend removing the reliance on `static` and start making more use of the `Doctors_Office` class (and OO principles in general)

For example...

```
public class DoctorsOffice {
    private int countNames = 0;
    private int comb = 5;
    private int waitTime;
    private String name;
    private Patient[] examRoom;

    public DoctorsOffice(String name, int waitTime, Patient[] examRoom) {
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
        this.name = name;
        this.examRoom = examRoom;
    }

    public void checkIn(String n) {
        if (countNames < examRoom.length) {
            int RmNmbr = countNames + 1;
            examRoom[countNames] = new Patient(n.toUpperCase(), 0);//Enter Patient into the empty exam room.
            countNames += 1;
            System.out.println("The Patient was checked into Exam Room number " + RmNmbr + ".");
            System.out.println(examRoom[countNames - 1].name + "    bloop   " + examRoom[countNames - 1].waitTime);

        } else if (countNames >= examRoom.length)//Exam Rooms are full
        {
            //wt = comb;
            // You have a wait time property, make use of it instead
            //WaitingRoom.add(new Patient(n.toUpperCase(), wt));//Enter Patient into the waiting room.
            System.out.println("The Exam Rooms are currently full. Patient was sent to the Waiting Room.");
            //System.out.println(WaitingRoom.peek().name + " has a wait time of " + WaitingRoom.peek().waitTime + " minutes.");
            countNames += 1;
            comb += 5;
        }
    }

    public void checkOut(String n) {
        int PatientExmRm;
        int index;
        int position;
        //if (Doctors_Office.ExamRmEmpty == true)
        if (countNames == 0) {
            System.out.println("There are not any Patients in the Exam Room to check out.");
        } //else if (Doctors_Office.ExamRmEmpty == false)// the Exam Room has patients.
        else if (countNames != 0) // the Exam Room has patients.
        {
            //String pName = ExamRoom[countNames - 1].name;
            //System.out.println(pName);
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < examRoom.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("bloop1");
                    if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(examRoom[i].name))// check if the target patient is in the exam room.
                    //if (ExamRoom[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n) )
                    {
                        System.out.println("bloop2");
                        PatientExmRm = i + 1;// Exam Room number that the patient is checking out of.
                        index = i;
                        Patient[] Copy = new Patient[examRoom.length - 1];
                        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < examRoom.length; j++) {
                            System.out.println("bloop3");
                            if (j == index) {
                                System.out.println("bloop4");
                                continue;
                            }
                            Copy[k++] = examRoom[j];
                            examRoom = Copy;
                            countNames -= 1;
                        }
                        System.out.println("The Patient " + n + " was sucessfully checked out of Exam Room " + PatientExmRm + ".");

                        //if (WaitingRoom.isEmpty() == true) {
                        //    System.out.println("There are not any Patients in the Waiting Room at this time");
                        //} else if (WaitingRoom.isEmpty() == false) {
                        //    position = index;
                        //    String QueuedPatient = WaitingRoom.peek().name;
                        //    Patient[] New = new Patient[ExamRoom.length + 1];
                        //    for (l = 0; l < ExamRoom.length + 1; l++) {
                        //        if (l < position - 1) {
                        //            New[l] = ExamRoom[l];
                        //        } else if (l == position - 1) {
                        //            New[l] = WaitingRoom.peek();
                        //            New[l] = WaitingRoom.remove();
                        //            New[l] = Patient(WaitingRoom.peek().name, WaitingRoom.peek().waitTime);
                        //        } else {
                        //            New[l] = ExamRoom[l - 1];
                        //        }
                        //    }
                        //    System.out.println("The Patient " + QueuedPatient + " was moved from the Waiting Room to Exam Room number " + PatientExmRm + ".");
                        //}
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The patient you are looking for is not in an Exam Room.");
                    }

                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a simple test using…

```
DoctorsOffice office = new DoctorsOffice("Jane", 0, new Patient[5]);
office.checkIn("Bob");
office.checkOut("Bob");
```

Shows that the core concept works - just remember, don't create a new instance of `DoctorsOffice` in your menu loop!

## Fourth...

Please take the time to learn and use the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-contents.html).

It will make your code easier to read/understand and it make easier for you to read/understand other peoples code.